# How to make the background fit the whole screen?

Tags: css, background

I am writing a website as part of my college course, but I have came across a problem. I can't seem to fit whole screen.

Please visit here to see what I mean: http://jsfiddle.net/xiiJaMiiE/gM3yk/

```
html, body 
{
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, right top, color-stop(0, #5977FF),
color-stop(1, #59C5FF));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-size:cover;
background-
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the height of html/body to 100%;

```
height: 100%;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gM3yk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Give parent `height` and `width`, and a suggested way is, to use `background-size:100% 100%;` rather than `background-size:cover;`

```
html, body {
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, right bottom, right top, color-stop(0, #5977FF), color-stop(1, #59C5FF));
    height: 100%;    /* added */
    width: 100%;    /* added */
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #5977FF 0%, #59C5FF 100%);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-size:100% 100%;    /* updated*/
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add

```
width:  100%;
height: 100%;
```